# Weight and biases storage ANN

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Sorry for the silly question but I am new of the ANN world, and since I am making a my own project i would like to know exactly everything I am doing.

So I still do not get how does the storage of weights and biases , in variables , works.

Are they put in an array or in a matrix? How does the position in these ones works then? And so on...

Comment: It's really up to you, as the one implementing the ANN. You certainly could use an array or matrix if you want. You just need to choose a way of keeping track of which edge each weight is associated with.

Answer (score 1):

Both an array or matrix can be used. But I suggest to use a matrix so you can more easily perform mathematical operations. For example when you need to multiply input and weight for the values of Hidden Sum, you can just use regular matrix multiplication.

for more details, try to check this video tutorial :
https://youtu.be/UJwK6jAStmg

or this web tutorial :
http://stevenmiller888.github.io/mind-how-to-build-a-neural-network/

those tutorial helped me so much to understand ANN.